# Why I got error parameter is not valid while retrieving image to picture box?

Tags: c#

I have written this code for retrieving image from database to picturebox. I got these error

> 'Parameter is not valid'

at this line `pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stm);`

```
Byte[] imagebyte = new Byte[0];
imagebyte = (Byte[])(dr["Pic_Image"]);
MemoryStream stm = new MemoryStream(imagebyte);
pictureBox1.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(stm);
```

would you please solve this error?

Comment: how you resolved that answer me

Comment: parameter missing here `Dim picture As Byte() = GetBytes(ListView2.Items(index).SubItems(8).Text)

        Dim converter As New ImageConverter()
        PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(converter.ConvertFrom(picture), Image)`

Answer (score 0):

When you provide the stream , it expects one of the following files :

> BMP
>
> GIF
>
> JPEG
>
> PNG
>
> TIFF

Make sure that your file is in one of these formats

Comment: parameter missing here `Dim picture As Byte() = GetBytes(ListView2.Items(index).SubItems(8).Text)

        Dim converter As New ImageConverter()
        PictureBox1.Image = DirectCast(converter.ConvertFrom(picture), Image)`